# If else on closed jsx tag

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Im looking to do an if else statement on the following piece of code in react
basically the function is supposed to load in retrieved data but i need to add that condition in once the loading is finish to check if my system has any items held and if not it reroutes to create said item.

```
return  (
            <Loader empty={true} loading={id === ""}>
               {!empty?
                <Table
                    data={resources}
                    columns={columns}
                    loadData={getItems}
                    queryObj={{id:id}}
                    searchEnabled={false}
                    noHeader={true}
                    customStyles={{
                        headCells: {
                            style: {
                                 fontWeight: 'bold'
                            },
                          },
                    }}
                />:<alternatefunctiontag id={id}/>}
            </Loader>
            )
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Im trying to query the data held by the table once the loading completes, this does not seem to allow me to do so

Answer (score 0):

You could return multiple Components based on your state like so:

```
if(loading === true ){
 return (
  <Loader/>
 )
}

if(loading === false && data === 'something'){
 return <LogicalComponent/> 
}

return  (
            <Loader empty={true} loading={id === ""}>
               {!empty?
                <Table
                    data={resources}
                    columns={columns}
                    loadData={getItems}
                    queryObj={{id:id}}
                    searchEnabled={false}
                    noHeader={true}
                    customStyles={{
                        headCells: {
                            style: {
                                 fontWeight: 'bold'
                            },
                          },
                    }}
                />:<alternatefunctiontag id={id}/>}
            </Loader>
            )
```

But you also can create multiple ternary operations like:

```
return (
 <div>
  {loading === true ? 
   <ComponentA/> 
   : loading === false ? <ComponentB/> 
   : loading === false && data === 'something' ? <ComponentC/>  
  }
 </div>
)
```

As you can see this solution is a bit messy. I don't know sure but hope thats what you need.

Also you can read more about ternary operators:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator